# Drop down list box

Tags: html

Do anyone know how to make the dropdown list box searchable by typing in it? I have checked some plugins like select2 and few others, but all of them are multiple options selectors. I want it to work same as dropdown list boxes except that it is searchable by typing in it

Comment: https://github.com/immense/immybox

Comment: http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

You could use Semantic-UI for this purpose. [Install](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/definition) the stylesheet(s) and the JavaScript scripts by it's instructions and place them into your HTML document.

---

Taken from the [Semantic-UI documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage):

> **Searching Dropdowns**
>
> Using a search selection dropdown will allow you users to search more
>   easily through large lists. This can also be converted directly from a
>   form select element.
>
> HTML code:
>
> ```
> <select class="ui search selection dropdown" id="search-select">
>   <option value="">State</option>
>   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
>   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
>   <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
>   <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
>   <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
>   <option value="CA">California</option>
>   <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
>   <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
>   <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
>   <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
>   <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
>   <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
>   <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
>   <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
>   <option value="TX">Texas</option>
>   <option value="UT">Utah</option>
>   <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
>   <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
>   <option value="WA">Washington</option>
>   <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
>   <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
>   <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
> </select>
> ```
>
> JavaScript code:
>
> ```
> $('#search-select')
>   .dropdown()
> ;
> ```